# Cannot use SSSE3 on enabled cpu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, intel, sse

I have a Xeon W3550 processor that is supposed to have support for the SSE4.2 instruction set but when I try and use anything past SSE2 in my c program I get a compiler error e.g.

```
#error "SSE4.2 instruction set not enabled"
```

When I use

```
$cat /procs/cpuinfo
```

it detects all relevant sse instruction sets but

```
$cpuid
```

only detects SSE and SSE2.

My operating system is ubuntu 11.04 with kernel 2.6.38-11-generic.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: An update based on Steve-o's comment below. The header files <*mmintrin.h> perform a check for the sse version that they are associated with by using #ifndef preprocessor directive e.g.

```
#ifndef __SSSE3__ 
#error "SSSE3 instruction set not enabled".
```

So I guess the question is then why is this coming back false despite the cpu being SSSE3 enabled.

Comment: Sounds like a GCC limitation, compilation of instructions is not limited to the host platform or architecture.  You would only notice the processor limit at runtime, with a seg fault or similar.

Comment: I used gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8 and I upgraded it to gcc-7.5 and g++-7.5 - it works like a charm!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try building with `-msse4.2`?

- Support for SSE4.2 built-in functions and code generation are
  available via -msse4.2.
- Both SSE4.1 and SSE4.2 support can be enabled via -msse4.

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html

Comment: No I didn't. This worked perfectly and my code is now compiling and running successfully using SSE3 commands, thanks!

Comment: There is also `-march=native` which will enable things based on what your CPU supports.